# Need patch versions of pkgs and can't find them

Tags: 14.04, package-management

Running 14.04.6 LTS.  My scanning tools indicate I need some packages that I can't find with dpkg, apt or apt-get and may be some other tools as well (I've been trying for several hours and it's all running together).  Add in that I am a Redhat admin and NOT a Ubuntu admin and there you have it.

For example. running `apt-get list -a php5\*` returns what I have installed and does not offer access to the pkgs listed below.  So, `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` does not appear to know about them, therefore I won't fix anything by running those commands.

Any way, I need

screen: Ubuntu 14.04 ESM (Trusty Tahr): released (4.1.0~20120320gitdb59704-9ubuntu0.1~esm1)

php5:

```
libapache2-mod-php5 - 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29+esm2
php5-cgi - 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29+esm2
php5-cli - 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29+esm2
php5-fpm - 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29+esm2
```

hostapd: hostapd - 2.1-0ubuntu1.7+esm1

wpasupplicant: wpasupplicant - 2.1-0ubuntu1.7+esm1

Any assistance will be appreciated.  I have read mountains of websites and even bought a copy of the *Trusty Tahr* book by R. Peterson.  Nothing so far that has helped.

Comment: On my 14.04 (ESM) those packages you mention are available but even newer. EX. php5-cli:  5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.29+esm12, hostpad: 1:2.1-0ubuntu1.7+esm2, ect. Are you on the ESM? See here, free for personal use,(scroll down),  not for commercial.. https://ubuntu.com/esm

Comment: I consdier @dougs response to be the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To receive 14.04 ESM updates, (for personal use),  one has to register which will then provide the repo source address, ect.

Go to https://ubuntu.com/esm, scroll down, click on `Get ESM Now` & follow the prompts to register.